# Trying to get drop down option on Select using Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function() {
  return $('.category w-select option:selected').text();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" class="category w-select" name="categories">
  <option value="" selected="selected">- Please select one -</option>
  <option value="1">Jewelry</option>
  <option value="2">Luxury Watch</option>
  <option value="3">Precious Metal or Stones</option>
  <option value="4">Electronics</option>
  <option value="5">Tools, Equipment</option>
  <option value="6">Musical Instruments, Equipment</option>
  <option value="7">Vehicle</option>
  <option value="8">Gun</option>
  <option value="9">Other</option>
  <option value="10">Antique, Collectible</option>
  <option value="11">Designer Wear &amp; Handbags</option>
</select>
```

Want get drop down option text on Return, But I have tried but not get any drop down option on retun. Do you have any idea I can i get value on retun option

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your selector for the `select` element is incorrect. You also need to place your code within a `change` event handler. Finally you need to deal with the value in the event handler - you can't return anything from an anonymous function. Try this:

```js
$('.category.w-select').change(function() { // Note the joined selector
    var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    // use selectedText here...
    console.log(selectedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" class="category w-select" name="categories">
  <option value="" selected="selected">- Please select one -</option>
  <option value="1">Jewelry</option>
  <option value="2">Luxury Watch</option>
  <option value="3">Precious Metal or Stones</option>
  <option value="4">Electronics</option>
  <option value="5">Tools, Equipment</option>
  <option value="6">Musical Instruments, Equipment</option>
  <option value="7">Vehicle</option>
  <option value="8">Gun</option>
  <option value="9">Other</option>
  <option value="10">Antique, Collectible</option>
  <option value="11">Designer Wear &amp; Handbags</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just a note on how you could improve this answer, explain usage of this and selector

Answer (score 1):

Just use the one class

```
$('.category option:selected').text()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshekarmel1/e71j1j3a/

Answer (score 0):

In the selectors either use only one class or use a `.` to seperate the classes and not a space. ie. `$('.category.w-select option:selected').text()` or `$('.category option:selected').text()`

Having the function in an onchange handler will help you to get the value whenever value changes. Without it function will be executed only when the document loads i.e a single time.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.category.w-select').on('change', function(){
     console.log( $('.category.w-select option:selected').text());
  })
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required="required" class="category w-select" name="categories">
  <option value="" selected="selected">- Please select one -</option>
  <option value="1">Jewelry</option>
  <option value="2">Luxury Watch</option>
  <option value="3">Precious Metal or Stones</option>
  <option value="4">Electronics</option>
  <option value="5">Tools, Equipment</option>
  <option value="6">Musical Instruments, Equipment</option>
  <option value="7">Vehicle</option>
  <option value="8">Gun</option>
  <option value="9">Other</option>
  <option value="10">Antique, Collectible</option>
  <option value="11">Designer Wear &amp; Handbags</option>
</select>
```